# Prove that $ \sum_{x=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{x!} = e -1 $

Tags: summation

I was playing around with factorials and integrals when I put $ \sum_{x=1}^ \infty  \frac{1}{x!}  $ in Wolfram Alpha

I got the result as equal to $e - 1$.

It was an amazing discovery for me.

I tried to prove it, but could go nowhere. I just know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \big(1 +  \frac{1}{x} \big)^{x} = e$.

Can anyone provide a pointer to what should I do ?

EDIT : Everyone is referring to the definition of the exponential function. Can you provide a more elementary proof ?

Comment: Doesn't it follow directly from the definition of $e=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x!}$?

Comment: Try to expand $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$ using the binomial formula, and then subtract 1 from each side

Comment: And how can that be proved ?

Comment: Find the Taylor series of $e^x$ about $x=0$. Let $x=1$. You get your series.

Comment: @Kaynex Sadly, those who know of Taylor series most likely know the answer to this problem.

Comment: @barakmanos It is always the case that we must question what our definition of $e$ is.

Comment: Good observation. This result is usually stated as $e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {n!}$, because $0! = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, when $x$ is a whole number, we can take the binomial expansion:

$$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1+1+\frac12\frac{x-1}{x}+\frac16\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x^2}+\dots$$

And as $x\to\infty$, each fraction goes to $1$, so we have

$$e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$

Though you need to make this more rigorous at the limit part if you want a good proof.

Comment: this is clear and intuitive. +1

Comment: @qbert Horribly rigorous-less, but yes, clear and intuitive I do think.

Comment: Thus is how Euler did it in one of his books, I believe.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger hm, interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Let $e$ be the number represented as the limit

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

It is easy to show ([See Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)) that the sequence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing.  It is also straightforward to show that the sequence is bounded above by $3$.  Hence, the limit exists.

---

From the binomial theorem, we can write

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^n}$$

Next, we note that for all $0\le k\le n$

$$\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^n}=\frac1{k!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)\le \frac1{k!}$$

Therefore, we see that

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^n}\le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}$$

Taking the $\limsup$ as $n\to \infty$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
e&\le \limsup_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\tag1
\end{align}$$

where we used the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$ converges (apply the ratio test, for example) to  arrive at $(1)$.

---

Next, we fix $m\le n$.  Then, clearly

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^n}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{k=0}^m \left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)\frac1{k!}
\end{align}$$

With $m$ fixed, we take the limit as $n\to \infty$ and find that

$$e\ge \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k!} \tag 2$$

Then, we let $m\to \infty$ in $(2)$ to obtain

$$e\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!} \tag 3$$

Finally, putting together $(1)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}$$

whence we see that

$$e-1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$

And we are done!

Comment: @simpleart I've added a rigorous development to compliment your solution.